# How can I know whether writing to a named pipe would block?

Tags: bash, fifo

I want to write to a named pipe only if it already has a reader.  Currently, I'm using `timeout` to detect whether the attempt to write to the pipe blocked, like so:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
rm -f pipe
mkfifo pipe
sleep 5

timeout 1 bash -c "echo Hello > pipe"

if [[ $? == 0 ]]
then
    echo Somebody got our message
else
    echo Nobody read from pipe, so we didn\'t send a message
fi
```

This works.  If I `tail -f pipe` in a separate terminal during the sleep I get one message, and if I don't, I get the other.  But is there a better way?  Ideally it would be something that doesn't rely on a timeout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to write to the pipe, only if there are some process that has opened it for reading, you could open it for writing in non-blocking mode.

With GNU `dd`:

```
echo Hello | dd oflag=nonblock of=pipe status=none &&
  echo message has been sent
```

And you'll get the error message for ENXIO (something like *No such device or address* in English) if there was no reader.

Note that it would also fail (with `EWOULDBLOCK`/`EAGAIN`, *Resource temporarily unavailable*) if the pipe is full (if there is a reader, but it is not currently reading and something like 64KiB have already been written to it).

Also note that not all of the message may be written if it wouldn't fit. If you remove the `status=none`, you'll see how much was written.

Comment: on bsd I get `dd: unknown operand oflag`